# How to set FSTrigger's folder path in Hudson CI integration tool?

Tags: hudson

I am using Hudson tool to automate tests for our project. I want to use FSTrigger plugin to trigger the build whenever there will a change in SVN. 
As i set Folder path to "http://192.16.17.121/test/test1/config/". It gives error that folder should exist, but it exists at specified location.I can view it directly from browser too.

Can anybody tell me whats the problem?Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify an absolute path to a directory on your filesystem.  What you have shown there is a URL.

An absolute path would look like this:

```
/var/www/html/test/test1/config
```