# How to trigger Jenkins job when a change is made in Server folders?

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I want to trigger my Jenkins Job when a particular folder is modified in WAS server.Is there any plugin available ? I tried with 'FSTrigger' plugin but it is working only for local machine folder changes but not for server side changes. I am getting following message in FSTrigger floder log.
Trying to monitor the folder 'https:\server_name\folder_path'
The directory 'https:\server_name\folder_path' doesn't exist.

Kindly help me on this.!!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this answer:
[How to set FSTrigger's folder path in Hudson CI integration tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744217/how-to-set-fstriggers-folder-path-in-hudson-ci-integration-tool)

I think you can only monitor a local URL, like:

```
/var/www/html/test/test1/config
```

To solve your problem, one solution is to connect your WAS server to your Jenkins master as a Jenkins slave.

And next, create a Jenkins job using the FSTrigger plugin and launch it on your WAS slave.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. Is there any other alternative method to achieve this ? since I don't have permission to install Jenkins on WAS Server. I am able to connect to server using SSH. So is there any possibility that I can run a SSH command to get the triggering point from my local Jenkins.

Comment: If you can expose the WAS folder with a HTTP URL, you can use the Trigger URL Plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/URLTrigger+Plugin

Comment: I can open the URL through Putty.

Comment: I did a quick check and it's not possible to check a remote folder using SSH and Jenkins :(

Comment: Yup even I tried and it's not supporting :( Only requirement is to trigger a Jenkins job whenever there is a code deployment in server. And I have left with no clues to achieve this !!